# How to increase line pattern density in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, patterns

I would like to have a square with diagonal hatching in Inkscapae 1.0. I followed the instructions in the question [Create hatching in Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45577/create-hatching-in-inkscape#):

1. I created a slanted line in the desired color and thickness.
2. I converted the line into a pattern.
3. I created the square and selected the new pattern.

The problem is the resulting line appears only once in the square:

[image: (1) square with single slanting line and (2) single slanting line]

How would I increase its number of appearances? I've tried creating an object with multiple parallel lines and using that as the pattern, but I had problems with discontinuities when the pattern was repeated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there appears to be [a bug in Inkscape 1.0](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/is-the-pattern-fill-broken/) which causes the pattern to be much larger than the one created. Hopefully they'll fix it in the next release.  The bug doesn't exist in 0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11) - I tested it in both versions.

Anyway, here's a workaround

1. Draw a horizontal line (don't draw it at an angle or the pattern won't work properly). Duplicate it and move it down using the down arrow key, so there's a gap between the two.
2. Select both lines and convert to a pattern
3. Draw a shape, and fill it with the pattern. It will probably create one thick horizontal line in the pattern fill.
4. Select the Edit paths by Nodes tool to scale and rotate the pattern fill by clicking and dragging the control points. You will probably have to zoom out to find them, because they will probably be located off the page.

Note: If you don't want to repeat this every time you want to fill other shapes with the same pattern, copy the object with the adjusted pattern, and do *Edit > Paste Style* to apply the adjusted pattern to other objects.

Example

[image]

Comment: Wow, not only did you give me answer but you tested it on two versions and created an animated gif! Thanks!